# UIPopoverController in UITabBarController works for only once

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Now i'm working on an iPad App, in which there is a `UITabBarController` with 9 view controllers and 9 `UITabBarItems`. When i click one item, called "ET", a `UIPopoverController` appears above the `UITabBarItem`, everything went fine for the first time, after i click on somewhere else outside the popover to make it disappear, then i click "ET" again it doesn't work. After some debugging, i found the view controller supposed to display in popover controller is removed from `UITabBarController.viewcontrollers`, now `UITabBarController` only has 8 view controllers. I've no idea where i removed it, here is my code for display the popover controller

```
-(void) PopViewController:(UIViewController*)pVC rect:(CGRect)rect type:(int)nType
{
if (pVC == NULL)
    return;

[self PushViewController:NULL type:0];
 GTJAMyNavigatorViewController*  navigationController = [[GTJAMyNavigatorViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pVC];
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO ];
if ([pVC isKindOfClass:[TZTUIETViewController class]]) {
self.popoverVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
}

self.popoverVC.delegate = self;
[navigationController setPopover:self.popoverVC];
[self.popoverVC presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                           inView:self.view
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                         animated:YES];

NSLog(@"%d",[self.popoverVC retainCount]);
```

}

here is the code of dismiss delegate method

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
if (self.popoverVC && self.popoverVC == popoverController)
{
    [((TZTUITabBar*)self.tabBar) UndoSelect];

    [self.popoverVC release];
    self.popoverVC = NULL;
}
 NSLog(@"%d",[self.popoverVC retainCount]);

return;
```

}

i've made self.popoverVC strong property, so can anybody help? Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure that the second time   if ([pVC isKindOfClass:[TZTUIETViewController class]]) is TRUE?

Comment: A view controller can only have one parent, so it's implicitly removed from the tab view controller when you set it as the root view controller of the navigation controller that you show in the popover.

Comment: Thanks guys. but how to fix this ? once i directly set pVC as the content view controller of the popover, it reports "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The content view controller argument must be the root of its associated view controller hierarchy.'" so i have to use navigation controller. @omz

Comment: No, you have to use a different view controller (of the same class).

Comment: you mean changing pVC to another VC which is also of the TZTUIETViewController class ?

Comment: @omz,problem is solved, thanks very muck!